# MySQL export query as insert statements

Tags: mysql, export

I have two mysql tables which both have a typeID in common.  I am wanting to select everything from these two tables with the same typeID, query below:

```
SELECT ta.requiredTypeID, ta.typeID, ta.quantity 
  FROM `invtypes` as t, `typeactivitymaterials` as ta 
  WHERE volume > 0 AND t.typeID = ta.typeID;
```

This gives me the correct results but I am trying to export this query as insert statements.  I have tried adding INTO OUTFILE "/path/" but this only exports the data as tab/comma delimited data, is it possible to export this data as insert statements?

Cheers

Eef

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can combine INSERT with SELECT to insert records directly from the result of a select statement.

The way you do it would be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO newtable (requiredTypeID, typeID, quantity)
     SELECT ta.requiredTypeID, ta.typeID, ta.quantity 
         FROM `invtypes` as t, `typeactivitymaterials` as ta 
         WHERE volume > 0 AND t.typeID = ta.typeID;
```

Here's a link to the relevant [MySQL manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html).

Note that this would actually do the insert right away; it wouldn't do quite what you asked (which is to generate the insert statements for use later on).

Answer (score 52):

You might be able to use `mysqldump` instead. Check out the parameters `--tables` and `--where=`.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: I think that would be the answer for the original question asked. It worked beautifully for me!

Comment: Yes, and can be a lot more useful if the instances are on different machines.

Answer (score 37):

If you have MySQL Workbench it can generate insert statements for you.

In the SQL editor run your query, then from the result set you can click the export button. Then in the "Save as Type" select as "SQL INSERT statements (*.sql)". Click Save, confirm the table you are exporting and click ok.

If you open the file you should see your result set as insert statements with the column names.

I only tested this on a simple select * from table. I haven't tested this with multiple tables. I hope this helps.

EDIT: Seems like workbench is available for Windows, OSX, and Linux (Thanks vcardillo)

Comment: Super handy, thanks. Didn't even notice the drop down for save as type. Thanks!

Comment: Oh also, MySQL Workbench exists also for OSX and Linux.

Comment: While doing this, SQL INSERT is not including Blob type column data

Answer (score 13):

Just leaving it here, if someone comes looking for the exact query for creating `MySQL` `export` query as `insert` statements. This answer uses  `mysqldump` as @a'r suggestion.

```sql
mysqldump -u<user-name> -p<password> mydb t1 t2 t3 > mydb_tables.sql
```

Answer (score 5):

You can make something like this:

```
select 
       concat(
         concat(
           concat(
             concat(
               concat(
                 concat('insert into <table> (requiredTypeID, typeID, quantity) values ("'
                        ,ta.requiredTypeID)
               ,'", "')
             ,ta.typeID)
           ,'", "')
         ,ta.quantity)
       ,'")')
FROM 
       `invtypes` as t, `typeactivitymaterials` as ta 
WHERE 
       volume > 0 AND t.typeID = ta.typeID;
INTO OUTFILE 'file_name'
```

I know it is ugly but I think it solves your case :)

Comment: concat can take more than two parameters.